# Determine if there are repeating numbers in a matrix (Python NumPy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In NumPy, If i have the matrix:

```
[2 4 3
 2 8 5
 7 6 9]
```

the number two appears twice. How can i check this and return a boolean saying true if so?

UPDATE: If the matrix is

```
[2 0 3
 1 5 0
 9 6 7]
```

How do i make it so that the zeros are ignored. There are two zeros here but we dont care about them and only want to return true if a number other than zero repeats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the np.unique with return counts like this:

```
c = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
(c[1]-1).any()
```

That will return true if any repeats exist in the array. You subtract 1 from it so that it does not include the values that only appear once. If you wanted to ignore the zeros you could just change that statement to this

```
c = np.unique(array[array != 0], return_counts=True)
(c[1]-1).any()
```

Comment: I've updated the question, How would you implement this new feature?

Answer (score 0):

Using np.unique(),

```
import numpy as np

def hasRepeated(arr):
    elements, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    if np.any(counts != 1): return True
    return False
    
    
arr = np.array(
    [[2,4,3],
    [2,8,5],
    [7,6,9]]
)

print(hasRepeated(arr)) #True
```

Comment: I've updated the question, How would you implement this new feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2],[2, 4]])
#convert matrix to list
a = a.tolist()
l = [value for sublist in a for value in sublist]
#use Counter for list, it gives a dictionary stating which element appeared how many times
from collections import Counter
C = Counter(l)
for val in C.values():
    if val > 1:
        print('True')
        break
```

for EDIT, change the last four lines of the code to:

```
for key,val in C.items():
    if key != 0 and val > 1:
        print('True')
        break
```